# Can I legally use fonts for my personal business if I'm using an adobe subscription my job has provided for me?

Tags: fonts, legal, font-licensing, adobe-creative-suite

I do graphic work at my job, and they supply me with a Creative Cloud membership. If I start my own business, can I legally use fonts provided by adobe even though my job is the one providing me the membership?

In other words, do I legally have the right to use the fonts commercially if my personal business is not connected with the company I work for?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You should read the [Font licensing FAQs on Adobe's site](https://www.adobe.com/products/type/font-licensing/licensing-faq.html). There's also a similar page with similar [FAQs for Adobe's Typekit fonts here](https://helpx.adobe.com/fonts/using/font-licensing.html). These answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Employment is a [work-for-hire](https://www.owe.com/resources/legalities/4-what-is-work-made-for-hire/) agreement. *Legally*, your employer is paying for licenses, that does **not** grant you permission to use those licenses outside the scope of your *employment*. Everything you have (and create) at your office is your *employer's* not yours. That include software and/or software subscriptions. Unless there's some written agreement in place with the employer relinquishing rights to you, you have no permission to use *anything* outside the scope of your employment.

It's not much different than if you wanted to take the desk you have at the office home and use the desk for your own business. It's the employer's property and you can't rightfully use it for another business unless the employer explicitly tells you that you can take the desk.

Comment: Okay that's what I thought, just wanted to make sure. thanks so much for your answer!